Subject: Query Regarding a Reward Claimed to Be from ERC-20/Ethereum
I recently received a notification about a reward linked to an ERC-20 smart contract. The reward claims to be 6 ETH and is associated with a condition to deposit 8,000 USDT within a specific time frame. However, I am unsure about the authenticity of this reward and its source.
Could you please clarify:

Is this reward officially provided by the Ethereum or ERC-20 network?

Why was this reward issued, and what are the exact terms and conditions?

How can I verify if this reward is legitimate?


I want to ensure this is not a scam and would appreciate your guidance on how to proceed safely.
Thank you in advance for your support.

100% a scam bro
